# Git ignores change to core.autocrlf

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I have core.autocrlf set to true. I want to change it to false. In Git Bash I ran

`git config --global core.autocrlf false`

but `git config --list` still shows `core.autocrlf=true`.

I have retried restarting Git Bash and running in an empty directory, i.e. not a repo but nothing seems to change it. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get when you run these 2 commands? `git config --get --local core.autocrlf`
`git config --get --global core.autocrlf`

Comment: @TeamTam, I get nothing for the first command (--local) and I get 'false' for the second (--global)! Why does the second differ from `git config --list`?

Comment: Git gets its configs from various sources (i.e. local, global, system). When you call `git config --list` it will show them all as-is without aggregating them IIRC. So I suspect that you just need to work out which config file your setting is coming from and the precedence of it.

Comment: @TeamTam Did you mean a latter line will overwrite a previous line?

Answer (score 8):

With git version 2.8 onwards, you can simply use:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

You will see which config is set where.

This should allow you to check if the core.autocrlf global setting is being overridden by a repository specific setting and might explain why it appears that the setting seems to be ignored.

Comment: thanks. This is what the --show-origin reveals:

`file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true`
`file:C://Users/<me>/.gitconfig     core.autocrlf=false`

So, I have two, and 'git config --list' only prints the one in ProgramData

Comment: Can you post the output of   `git config --list | grep autocrlf` and `git config --list --show-origin | grep autocrlf` in your question  please? Also what is the version of Git for Windows that you are using?